# intersection of sectors with different centers

Tags: geometry

Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would like you guys to point me to a direction I need to go to solve the following problem:

I have multiple points in cartesian space. From each point there is a sector, which is defined by its center and angular width. These sectors intersect each other multiple times, creating a number of polygons, which do not intersect with other polygons. I want to find these polygons.

From graphics point of view, I could simply draw them all in one picture with fixed opacity, and then analyze color on the picture to find areas with biggest intensity. Unfortunately, problem is kinda big in its size, and I can't do that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your 3rd paragraph makes it a little clearer : say me if have well understood : you want to get at first the (non void !) polygon which is the intersection of a maximum number of sectors, then the second one  with no common area with the first, etc. ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, exactly.